# Iterated Expecation of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation

I'm trying to show that
$$
E[(Y- E[Y|X])(E[Y|X] - E[Y])] = 0.
$$
My attempt is as follows:
\begin{align*}
& E[(Y- E[Y|X])(E[Y|X] - E[Y])] \\
  &= E[YE[Y|X] - Y E[Y] - E[Y|X]^2 +E[Y|X]E[Y]]\\
  &= E[YE[Y|X]] - E[Y E[Y]] - E[E[Y|X]^2] +E[E[Y|X]E[Y]]\\
  &= E[E[Y|X]E[Y|X]] - E[E[Y|X] E[Y]]\\
  &\qquad - E[E[Y|X]^2] +E[E[Y|X]E[Y]]\\
  &= 0
\end{align*}

However, I seemed to have misused the law of iterated expectations when I set
$$
E[YE[Y|X]] = E[E[Y|X]E[Y|X]].
$$
How can I justify this? Or is it just wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E[Y\mid X]$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, hence 
$$ E[Y\mid X]^2 = E[YE[Y\mid X]\mid X] $$
giving 
$$ E \bigl[E [Y \mid X]^2\bigr] = E\bigl[ E[YE[Y\mid X]\mid X] \bigr] = E\bigl[YE[Y\mid X]\bigr]. $$